# Unexpected shape for Pandas column of np array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has two columns (l_cats and r_cats) of type np array.  Here is sample data

```
l_name,l_cats,l_gh,r_name,r_cats,r_gh,score
piggly wiggly,1|2|4|0|0,1,piggly wiggly,1|2|4|3|0,1,1
piggly wiggly,1|2|4|0|0,1,piggly wiggly,1|2|4|3|0,1,1
piggly wiggly,1|2|4|0|0,1,piggly wiggly,1|2|4|3|0,1,1
piggly wiggly,1|2|4|0|0,1,piggly wiggly,1|2|4|3|0,1,1
.................
.................
<79 rows>
```

Below is how I read the data into these two columns

```
 data = pd.read_csv(self.path, converters={'l_cats': lambda x: np.array([y for y in x.split('|')]),
                                                  'r_cats': lambda x: np.array([y for y in x.split('|')])})
flat = data['l_cats'].values
print(str(flat.shape))
# Output: (79,)
print(str(flat[0].shape))
# Output: (5,)
print(str(type(flat[0])))
# Output: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Shouldn't the output of `print(str(flat.shape))` be (79, 5) ?

Comment: Hello! What is `X_train`? How is it different from `data`?

Comment: sorry, it's the same data. I will edit the question to reflect this

Comment: Yes, I thought that. I'll also edit my answer for consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.
If you just do `print(flat)` you should understand why. This is `flat`:

```
[array(['1', '2', '4', '0', '0'], dtype='<U1')
 array(['1', '2', '4', '0', '0'], dtype='<U1')
 array(['1', '2', '4', '0', '0'], dtype='<U1')
 array(['1', '2', '4', '0', '0'], dtype='<U1')]
```

As you see, it's not a 2D matrix, but a 1D array or 1D arrays. To convert it to a 2D matrix you could do:

```
mtx = np.stack(flat)
```